# Concrete 5 on NGINX Server, Backend JS not loading

Tags: nginx, concrete5

I've created a Concrete5 site which was running on Apache for 1 year, after that I switched to a host that uses NGINX instead of Apache, this host does not allow full access to NGINX, only the needed.

The host does provide this code for Wordpress and this seems to work for Concrete5 too:

```
location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite  ^(.*)$  /index.php?/$1 last;
        break;
    }
}
```

Every frontend page is loading, but while in admin mode, the navigationbar doesn't show up, and so does every modal.

Anyone ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a good How-To article on the concrete5 website regarding NGINX, you should give it a look here: http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/how-tos/developers/nginx-with-fastcgi_cache-php5-fpm/

Domain Configuration .conf file:

```
location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
}

set $skip_cache 0;

# POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
if ($request_method = POST) {
    set $skip_cache 1;
}
if ($query_string != "") {
    set $skip_cache 1;
}
if ($http_cookie ~ "CONCRETE5") {
    set $skip_cache 1;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$uri;
    if (!-f $request_filename){
        set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
    }
    if (!-d $request_filename){
        set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
    }
    if ($rule_0 = "21"){
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
    }
}
```